# Search GC replicas and find AD account

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I have an issue which is to do with AD replication. We use a 3rd party app the create accounts in AD and then a powershell script (called by the app) to create the exchange accounts.
In the 3rd party app we can not tell which GC the ad account has been created on and therefore have to wait 20 minutes for replication to happen.

What I am trying to do is find which GC the account has been created on or is replicated to and connect to that server using....

```
set-adserversettings -preferredserver $ADserver
```

I currently have the below script and what I can't work out is to get it to stop when it finds the account and assign that GC to the $ADserver variable. The write-host line is only there for testing.

```
$ForestInfo = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$GCs = $ForestInfo.FindAllGlobalCatalogs()
Import-module activedirectory

ForEach ($GC in $GCs)
{
Write-Host $GC.Name
Get-aduser $ADUser
}
```

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether `Get-ADUser` returns more than 0 objects to determine whether the GC satisfied your query. After that, use `Set-ADServerSettings -PreferredGlobalCatalog` to configure the preference

You will need to specify that you want to search the Global Catalog and not just the local directory. The Global Catalog is accessible from port 3268 on the DC, so it becomes something like:

```
$ForestInfo = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$GCs = $ForestInfo.FindAllGlobalCatalogs()
Import-module ActiveDirectory

$ADUserName = "someusername"
$ADDomainDN = "DC=child,DC=domain,DC=tld"
$FinalGlobalCatalog = $null

foreach ($GC in $GCs)
{
    $GCendpoint = "{0}:3268" -f $GC.Name
    $SearchResult = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(samaccountname=$ADUserName))" -Server $GCEndpoint -SearchBase $ADDomainDN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if(@($SearchResult).Count -gt 0){
        $FinalGlobalCatalog = $GC
        break
    }
}

if($FinalGlobalCatalog){
    Write-Host "Found one: $($FinalGlobalCatalog.Name)"
    Set-ADServerSettings -PreferredGlobalCatalog $FinalGlobalCatalog.Name
} else {
    Write-Host "Unable to locate GC replica containing user $ADUserName"
}
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly in our development domain but when I tried it in our UAT domain it fails. I get an error 0x51 saying the ldap server is unavailable when I try `set-adserversettings -viewentireforest:$true -preferredserver $ADServer`

Comment: LDAP error 0x51 simply means that the `$ADServer` did not respond to an LDAP request, could be that `$ADServer` is either not a Domain Controller, the request is being blocked by a firewall or the name cannot be resolved. The snippet in my answer does **not** contain any mentions of your `$ADServer` - could it be that you hardcoded a reference to a Domain Controller from your test environment into that variable and forgot about it when you copy-pasted to the new environment? :)